# bash: alias: alias: not found

Tags: bash, alias

When I log in, I see the error:

> bash: alias: alias: not found

If I `source` my `.bashrc` file, the message appears again.

What is causing this?

Answer (score 43):

I had the same issue, so the solution is to follow simply rules.

```
alias alias_name='command '
```

no other symbols between equal sign.
I had whitespaces between the sign and the `source ~/.bashrc` always failed for me.
so be attentive

Comment: This solved my problem.

Comment: It solved mine as well ಠ_ಠ

Comment: I copy/pasted from another source and instead of a line break after each alias it added spaces. What appeared to be fine was not. Save yourself a headache and make sure each line ends in a linebreak.

Answer (score 7):

It turns out that a line feed had been removed from `~/.bashrc`, giving:

```
alias ll='ls -alF' alias la='ls -A'
alias l='ls -CF'
```

Breaking the first line into two commands fixes the error.

Answer (score 4):

In my case, removing spaces in `alias = ls -alF` solved the problem.

Comment: If the command has spaces in it, surround it with single or double quotes.

Answer (score 3):

My problem is solved when I remove the space in

```
alias cdg = 'ls -al'
```

to

```
alias cdg='ls -al'
```

Answer (score 2):

You can put quotes around the commands you are aliasing. You can even put them around the alias, too.

```
'llg'='ll | grep'
```

Newlines are also a problem. Widows-saved `.bashrc` file caused errors in Ubuntu virtual machine:

```
command not found
```

I ran `dos2unix .bashrc` to convert the line endings, and then everything worked.

Comment: dos2unix did the trick for me

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this:

```
alias 'll=ls -alF'
```